# jQuery custom content scroller speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery custom content scroller in a web app, but I have a problem with speed. In the documentation, I see what methods should be used, but it is still slow to me.

This is my code

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "light",

    });
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom", {
    scrollInertia: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
 $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollInertia: 500,
        autoHideScrollbar: true,
        theme: "light",
        advanced: {
            updateOnContentResize: true
        }
    });
```